# How to generate api request using curl in PHP

Tags: php, json, api, multipart

I'm trying to send the image url in post method to the given endpoint api URL but they said "The problems is related to the fact that your request is sending the image URL but the API is expecting a multipart/form-data request with the data of the image embedded in the request."

```
    "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "https://api-pro.jivo.com/api/image",
    "httpVersion": "unknown",
    "headers": [
        {
            "name": "Accept",
            "value": "application/json"
        },
        {
            "name": "Referer",
            "value": "https://pro.jivo.com/advert"
        },
        {
            "name": "Origin",
            "value": "https://pro.jivo.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "User-Agent",
            "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
        },
        {
            "name": "Authorization",
            "value": "Bearer xxxxxxxx"
        },
        {
            "name": "Content-Type",
            "value": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryq3A6Lz2bINdfNick"
        }
    ],
    "queryString": [],
    "cookies": [],
    "headersSize": -1,
    "bodySize": 295,
    "postData": {
        "mimeType": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryq3A6Lz2bINdfNick",
        "text": "------WebKitFormBoundaryq3A6Lz2bINdfNick\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"; filename=\"shippable.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryq3A6Lz2bINdfNick\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image_collection_id\"\r\n\r\n175\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryq3A6Lz2bINdfNick--\r\n"
    }
}
```

This is the image `http://mai.com/images/DC/Avanti.jpe` i have to sent using post using cURL PHP.

Please help me resolve this issue

Here is my code

```
$imagedata = array(
        'text' => new CURLFile(
            'http://mai.com/images/DC/Avanti.jpeg', 
            'multipart/form-data'
         ),"image_collection_id"=>186

    );

    $headers2= array('Accept: application/json','Referer: https://pro.tradus.com/advert','Origin: https://pro.jivo.com','Content-Type: multipart/form-data',"Authorization: Bearer " . $access_token,'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36'); 
    $ch2 = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-pro.jivo.com/api/image');
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers2);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$imagedata);
    $response2 = curl_exec($ch2);
    $err = curl_error($ch2);
    curl_close($ch2);
    echo $response2;
```

Comment: Try to send base64 encoded image data instead of image url

Comment: @SatyapalSharma:Thanks, but it's not generating the with required JSon Format

Comment: "not generating the with required JSon" Didn't get what are trying to say. Please be more specific.

Comment: i want to send request as mentioned in 1st code block, please let me know how to send the request